# Google Maps embed code not working

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have 3 websites with this google maps code which is working fine:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script>

function initialize() {  
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(38.7223956, -9.1358012);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 16,
    center: myLatlng
  }
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng,
      map: map,
      title: 'Something'
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
<style>
    h1 { background:none; padding:0; }
    #map-canvas {
        width:100%;
        height:250px;        
      }
</style>

<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

It's working great also if I'm just putting it on an html file on my hard drive.
Recently, I started a Wordpress project on my localhost and I don't know why but when I'm adding this code to my project I get this:

[Oops! Something went wrong](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a0Dos.jpg)

Obviously I have already wordpress websites that working with the same exact code, I have no idea why suddenly I'm getting this message, It's unbelievable

Answer (score 3):

Judging by your link it looks like you're not setting an API key.  If you are using the Google Maps API on a domain that was not active prior to June 22nd, 2016, it will require a key going forward.

See this link for an answer: https://www.latecnosfera.com/2016/06/google-maps-api-error-missing-keymap-error-solved.html

Answer (score 0):

The Google Maps Javascript API requires an [API key](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key).

Enforcement began some time in June I believe, but sites with a decent amount of traffic which were already using the API without a key got grandfathered in and don't have to comply (yet). That's why your other sites still work but new ones do not.

Comment: yep, works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/sydL9smg/

(open the console to see the google maps object)